# wxWidgets 2.8 (and before) wxTreeListCtrl missing, what did we do before 2.9?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

In wxPython 2.6 and above there's a "Gizmo" - wxTreeListCtrl which is as the name suggests a tree view with columns, or a list view with a column represented as a tree. I've come from wxPython to wxWidgets and wxTreeListCtrl was added in 2.9.3 (documentation).

What did people do before? 20 years (1993?) can't have elapsed with only the python lot going "you know what, I'd love some columns on this tree data...", I've been searching and searching but it's very hard, at the time nobody specified "wx 2.8" or 2.6, and it's hard to separate the results from those pertaining to 2.9 and above. Which is why I ask here.

Answer (score 1):

at least in the 2.8.9 you could have used the wxDataViewCtrl to display tree like data. I havent checked the documentation for the earlier releases but I suppose it was the same back then.

Comment: wxDataViewControl only uses a list, they explicitly say "currently this is the only type" meaning they have yet to do it. I was shocked the data view stuff is so recent TBH.

Comment: You were right with the "being planned" but I am 100% sure it displays also tree like data (for i have it used this way already). I guess back then you needed to be experienced at using wxWidgets/wxPython and create your own controls

Comment: There is a tree ctrl already? You may be using a later version. I cannot/don't want to leave 2.8 yet, (I just left 2.6) and I find it hard to believe that in 20 years no one created a gizmo or something to do it (unlike wxPython, which has Bind in 2.6!)

Comment: `wxDataViewCtrl` supported tree structure since the very beginning and this is indeed what you should use. I also **strongly** recommend you to go directly to 3.0 because 2.8 is 7 years old and not developed any longer and `wxDataViewCtrl` in particular has been significantly enhanced in 3.0.

Comment: @VZ. My 2.8.12 is 2011? I had no idea it was that old!

Comment: 2.8.12 is indeed from "only" a couple of years ago, but only bug fixes have been ever applied to 2.8 branch since its creation (and not all bug fixes as some of them broke ABI or were too extensive to apply to the stable branch). So at features level it's the same as 2.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

The gizmos library was available to wxWidgets users as well in 2.8 and earlier, look in the contrib folder of the source tree.  To use it you just need to build the gizmos library in an extra build step.  If you are on a platform using configure then the Makefile is already built for you when you ran configure, just go into the {bld}/contrib/src/gizmos folder and run make like usual.

Starting with 2.9 gizmos has been moved out of the wxWidgets source to the wxCode project.

Comment: I've got the LED control, and a tree with an information panel, and a scrolled splitter in my wxWIDGETS gizmos (wxPython, I've been using the tree list ctrl for years)